# What Does '?' Mean When Defining Prisma Schema Model?

Tags: prisma-graphql

In [this example](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/tools-and-interfaces/prisma-schema#example), we see:

`name      String?`

Not completely sure on what the `?` signifies here...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This means in DB. This field can be null. It's optional.

Comment: I know `!` means 'required...' so strange that we would need `?` to specify 'optional.' What would be the difference with just omitting `!`?

Comment: In prisma version one they using `!` but in version 2 they using `?`